# error SQL (Update Set Where) on submit

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update, syntax-error

I am currently having an issue getting the following code to update MySQLi after the user inputs in a text type form:

```
print "<input type='text' name='prof' >Prof<br />";    

$profselectorX=$_POST['prof'];
$profselector=$mysqli->real_escape_string($profselectorX);

$query="UPDATE homework1 SET 'prof'='".$profselector."' WHERE idnumber='".$editselector."'";
$resultz=$mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use backticks(`col_name`) for column name instead of single quotes('col_name')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your query like this

```
$query="UPDATE `homework1` SET `prof`='$profselector' WHERE `idnumber`='$editselector'";
```